# Using kNN with weighted dataset

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, weighting

I have a dataset df:

|  | category | var 1 | ... | var 32 | weighting | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 1.0 |  | 54.2 | 3.0 | US |
| 2 | pink | 0.0 |  | 101.0 | 1.0 | other |
| 3 | blue | 1.0 |  | 49.9 | 3.0 | US |
| 4 | green | 1.0 |  | 72.2 | 9.0 | US |

I'm using the kNN classifier (on the country variable)  but need it to take into account the current dataset weights I have included.
After looking at the sklearn pack I can see the KNeighborsClassifier() does have a weight argument, can I set this argument 'weight = df.weighting'? or do I have to go about this another way?

Comment: No you cannot, as the documentation said, if you pass a callable, it need "a user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the weights". But you simply add the weighting column to the other predictors.

Comment: And remember to scale your data before pass it to the KNN ;)

Comment: This may be a silly question but would it not be possible to create an array from the inverse of my weighting column and apply that to the weights argument? This would allow the observations with higher weights to be placed closer to the unlabelled point.

Answer (score 0):

you can explode samples by weight, for example, or you can think about creating custom weighted distance function

```
for weight, x_sample, y_sample in zip(sample_weights, X, y):
    weighted_X.extend([x_sample] * int(weight))
    weighted_y.extend([y_sample] * int(weight))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, would you be able to break down what this code is doing for me? I'm quite new to python and it's a bit of a new concept for me to get my head around.

Comment: it simple explode your dataset - for example for 1 row it creates another 2 duplictated rows and so on